# Knockout JS - Keyboard not working with Input keyup event - issue in android phone

Tags: knockout.js

Knockout JS - Keyboard not working with Input keyup event - issue in android phone

html -

js-       self.varificationKeyDown = function (data, event) {
console.log('key down:::', event);

```
    if (event.delegateTarget.id) {
      let currentId = parseInt(event.delegateTarget.id.charAt(event.delegateTarget.id.length - 1));
      if (event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 46) {
        event.preventDefault();
        self.isConfirmCodeDisabled(true);
        let tempOutput = self.varificationCode();
        tempOutput = tempOutput.slice(0, -1);
        self.varificationCode(tempOutput);
        let nextId = 'digit' + (currentId - 1);
        if (self.showCodeValidationErrors()) {
          self.resetToConfirm();
        }
        if (currentId < 2) {
          self.varificationCode("");
          return;
        } if (currentId < 5) {
          document.getElementById(nextId).value = "";
          tempOutput = self.varificationCode();
          tempOutput = tempOutput.slice(0, -1);
          self.varificationCode(tempOutput);
        }
        document.getElementById(nextId).focus();
        return;
      }
      if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        self.isConfirmCodeDisabled(false);
        document.getElementById('confirm-varification-btn').click();
        return;
      }
      const elemValue = document.getElementById('digit' + currentId).value;
      var valid = !Number.isNaN(parseInt(elemValue)) && elemValue < 10 && elemValue > -1 && /^[0-9]$/i.test(event.key);
      if (valid) {
        let temOutput = self.varificationCode() ? self.varificationCode() : "";
        const nextId = currentId + 1;
        if (nextId > 4) {
          temOutput += document.getElementById('digit' + currentId).value + "";
          self.varificationCode(temOutput);
          self.isConfirmCodeDisabled(false);
          return;
        } else {
          if (document.getElementById('digit' + currentId).value) {
            document.getElementById('digit' + (currentId + 1)).focus();
          }
        }
        temOutput += document.getElementById('digit' + currentId).value + "";
        self.varificationCode(temOutput);
      } else {
        document.getElementById('digit' + currentId).value = "";
      }
    }

  }
```

keyup event kayboard not working.
Can anyone please help